# Deploy war to remote nodejs server

Tags: node.js, maven, jenkins, gruntjs

We have a nodejs server running on a remote machine and we want to deploy a build (war file) from our jenkins server on that server/machine to run automated tests. The war is a front-end module (javascript, html etc).

The file has to be deployed on a specific path and unpacked for the nodejs server to refer to it.

Have been looking at grunt and maven plugins but found no obvious solution.

Suggestions?

Comment: Yes, I recommend you to search from Google

Comment: It sounds as if some ant tasks will be best for this. So you can use SSH to login to the remote server, copy files, unpack them, just the way you need it. if you can use a running tomcat the maven-cargo-plugin will probably help (it allows to deploy into tomcat via the tomcat manager).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Maven Wagon Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/wagon/) should be able to do what you are looking for.